# Kendo Grid can't reload template again after remove row data?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

When I `remove` the second line of data, a field on the first line appears `undefined`, that is, unable to execute the `template`：
[image]

```js
{
    field: "professionLevel",
    title: '<@spring.message "技能等级"/>',
    width: 120,
    template: function (dataItem) { //meaning of the template: Just convert English to Chinese,
        for (var i = 0; i < professionLevelData.length; i++) {
            if (professionLevelData[i].value === dataItem.professionLevel) {
                return dataItem.professionLevel = professionLevelData[i].meaning;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're doing something else wrong. With the code you provided I cant salvage enough to reproduce the problem so I will present you with a simple working case (similar to your template logic):

```
var data = [
    {id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33},
    {id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30},
    {id: 3, name: "Bob Doe", age: 22}
];

var translate = [
    {value: 1, translate: "traslate 1"},
    {value: 2, translate: "traslate 2"},
    {value: 3, translate: "traslate 3"}
];

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
        {
            field: "name",
            template: function (dataItem) {
                var returnValue = dataItem.name;

                for (var i = 0; i < translate.length; i++) {
                    if (dataItem.id === translate[i].value) {
                        returnValue = translate[i].translate;
                    }
                }

                return returnValue;
            }
        },
        {field: "age"},
        {command: "destroy"}
    ],
    dataSource: {
        data: data,
        schema: {
            model: {id: "id"}
        }
    },
    editable: true,
    remove: function (e) {
        console.log("Removing", e.model.name);
    }
});
```

Example: [Translate example](https://dojo.telerik.com/iBAGofOk)

If this doesn't solve your problem please expand the question with relevant data.

PS. With `return dataItem.professionLevel = professionLevelData[i].meaning;` you are updating grids data source, are you sure you want to update it? Or just show meaning in table? In that case just `return professionLevelData[i].meaning;`

Comment: Xie Xie,that's really a big help